# Logging format python 2.5.2

Tags: python, django, logging

Im using python 2.5.2 and django 1.3.2
My setting is with this logging format, it is correctly?

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {

},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'log.CommonAdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
}
```

And this error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in   __call__
 self.load_middleware()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in  load_middleware
for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
 self._setup()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
 self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
 logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/dictconfig.py", line 553, in dictConfig
  dictConfigClass(config).configure()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/dictconfig.py", line 352, in configure
  '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'mail_admins': super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

When I remove the Logging block, its start ok.
Any idea?

Comment: Wow that is a very old version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing value of 'class' with -

> django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler

For more info - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging